# How to share a folder on the network for a specific computer

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, network-shares, shared-folders

I have a computer and a laptop (both Windows 10) and I want to share one folder from my computer so I can access it from my laptop. I went to Advanced Sharing and shared the folder but now, anyone from my network can access that folder. Is there any way I can limit this share so only my laptop can access the folder?

Comment: "Is there any way I can limit this share so only my laptop can access the folder?" - You have to setup Advanced Sharing but you can configure an individual file or folder to be only shared with specific users.   Just view the share properties of the file or folder.  If you are still confused clarify your question

Comment: What needs to be further clarified?

Comment: I already went into properties but there I can only set the folder to be shared with specific users on that same computer, I can't find my laptop